# Looping through an array of objects based on a child (not a parent) node

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, dictionary

I'm still learning the more advanced ways of interacting with arrays. This problem has be stumped.

In my React app, I'm creating a Material-UI table, which populates its rows from an array of objects. I'm used to mapping and filtering arrays from top to bottom, from parent to child. However, in my case, I need to loop over my data based on one of the *child* keys.

Here's the simulated data:

```
const dogs = {
  locations: [
    {
      state: "CT",
      dogBreeds: [
        {
          breed: 'Beagle',
          breedDescription: "High-energy, tends to howl",
          cost: 1200
        },
        {
          breed: 'Bulldog',
          breedDescription: "Low-energy; good apartment dog",
          cost: 1400
        },
        {
          breed: 'Doberman',
          breedDescription: "Good disposition, needs lots of exercise",
          cost: 1700
        }
      ]
    }
    {
      state: "RI",
      dogBreeds: [
        {
          breed: 'Beagle',
          breedDescription: "High-energy, tends to howl",
          cost: 1200
        },
        {
          breed: 'Bulldog',
          breedDescription: "Low-energy; good apartment dog",
          cost: 1400
        },
        {
          breed: 'Doberman',
          breedDescription: "Good disposition, needs lots of exercise",
          cost: 1700
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

In each table row, I need to display the data like so:

State * Breed * Breed Description * Cost

However, as you can see, each state only occurs once but can contain one or more breeds. So, how do I correctly loop, map, or otherwise traverse this data so that I end up with an object that looks like this:

```
row = [
  {
    state: "CT",
    breed: "Beagle",
    breedDescription: "High-energy, tends to howl",
    cost: 1200
  },
  {
    state: "CT",
    breed: 'Bulldog',
    breedDescription: "Low-energy; good apartment dog",
    cost: 1400
  },
  {
    state: "CT",
    breed: 'Doberman',
    breedDescription: "Good disposition, needs lots of exercise",
    cost: 1700
  },
  {
    state: "RI",
    breed: "Beagle",
    breedDescription: "High-energy, tends to howl",
    cost: 1200
  },
  {
    state: "RI",
    breed: 'Bulldog',
    breedDescription: "Low-energy; good apartment dog",
    cost: 1400
  },
  {
    state: "RI",
    breed: 'Doberman',
    breedDescription: "Good disposition, needs lots of exercise",
    cost: 1700
  }
]
```

I am using ES6 methods, and have tried everything from `map()` to `for/each` to `for` loops. So far, nothing has produced the results I need. Hoping I'm just overthinking it and this is trivial for a more experienced developer. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for the [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function

```
const row = dogs.locations.reduce((acc, loc) => {
  const breeds = loc.dogBreeds.map(breed => {
    return {
      ...breed,
      state: loc.state
    }
  })
  return acc.concat(breeds)
}, [])
```

Comment: [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992), please?

Comment: Azium, thank you SO much...this was the perfect solution! Clearly, I need to become more familiar with the reduce() method.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a simple way to solve your problem.

**Code:**

```
const rows = [];
dogs.locations.forEach((location) => {
  location.dogBreeds.forEach((item) => {
    const row = [];
    row.push(location.state);
    row.push(item.breed);
    row.push(item.breedDescription);
    row.push(item.cost);
    rows.push(row);
  });
});
```

**Output:**

```
rows: [
    [ 'CT', 'Beagle', 'High-energy, tends to howl', 1200 ],
    [ 'CT', 'Bulldog', 'Low-energy; good apartment dog', 1400 ],
    [
      'CT',
      'Doberman',
      'Good disposition, needs lots of exercise',
      1700
    ],
    [ 'RI', 'Beagle', 'High-energy, tends to howl', 1200 ],
    [ 'RI', 'Bulldog', 'Low-energy; good apartment dog', 1400 ],
    [
      'RI',
      'Doberman',
      'Good disposition, needs lots of exercise',
      1700
    ]
  ]
```

**Update #1**
Thanks Scott Sauyet for your suggestions. I didn't understand well the question but I Think with a little change will work:

```js
const dogs = {
  locations: [
    {
      state: 'CT',
      dogBreeds: [
        {
          breed: 'Beagle',
          breedDescription: 'High-energy, tends to howl',
          cost: 1200,
        },
        {
          breed: 'Bulldog',
          breedDescription: 'Low-energy; good apartment dog',
          cost: 1400,
        },
        {
          breed: 'Doberman',
          breedDescription: 'Good disposition, needs lots of exercise',
          cost: 1700,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      state: 'RI',
      dogBreeds: [
        {
          breed: 'Beagle',
          breedDescription: 'High-energy, tends to howl',
          cost: 1200,
        },
        {
          breed: 'Bulldog',
          breedDescription: 'Low-energy; good apartment dog',
          cost: 1400,
        },
        {
          breed: 'Doberman',
          breedDescription: 'Good disposition, needs lots of exercise',
          cost: 1700,
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};
const rows = [];
dogs.locations.forEach((location) => {
  location.dogBreeds.forEach((item) => {
    rows.push(Object.assign({state: location.state},item));
  });
});
console.log(rows);
```

Comment: Thanks very much, Jose! Your answer works, too. I used the first answer because the reduce() method works a little better in my context (it allows me to perform the mapping on the data directly, without needing to initialize an empty array). Even so, this, too, was helpful!

Answer (score 1):

A combination of `map` and `flatMap` can be used to do this in a clean manner:

```js
console .clear ()

const dogs = {locations: [{state: "CT", dogBreeds: [{breed: 'Beagle', breedDescription: "High-energy, tends to howl", cost: 1200}, {breed: 'Bulldog', breedDescription: "Low-energy; good apartment dog", cost: 1400}, {breed: 'Doberman', breedDescription: "Good disposition, needs lots of exercise", cost: 1700}]}, {state: "RI", dogBreeds: [{breed: 'Beagle', breedDescription: "High-energy, tends to howl", cost: 1200}, {breed: 'Bulldog', breedDescription: "Low-energy; good apartment dog", cost: 1400}, {breed: 'Doberman', breedDescription: "Good disposition, needs lots of exercise", cost: 1700}]}]}

const extractBreeds = (dogs) => 
  dogs.locations.flatMap(
    ({state, dogBreeds}) => dogBreeds.map(breed => ({state, ...breed}))
  )

console .log (extractBreeds (dogs))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

At the outer level we `flatMap` in order to combine the generated arrays into one.  In the inside, we use `map`, and with a little parameter destructuring and the spread operator (`...`), we can convert the individual items.

Comment: I totally forgot that flatMap was introduced. remember smooshMap? those there good times

Comment: @azium: It's not hard to simulate `flatMap` with `map` followed by `reduce` with `concat`, but having it makes a number of things much nicer.  For instance, we can easily write `const filterMap = (f, g) => (xs) => xs .flatMap (x => f(x) ? [g(x)] : [])`.  And yes, `smoosh` was just an idea ahead of its time.  I still take the `contains`/`includes` foofaraw too personally

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan). It is more flexible, but there is obviously a trade-off in introducing another dependency

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const dogs = { locations: [{ state: 'CT', dogBreeds: [{ breed: 'Beagle', breedDescription: 'High-energy, tends to howl', cost: 1200 }, { breed: 'Bulldog', breedDescription: 'Low-energy; good apartment dog', cost: 1400 }, { breed: 'Doberman', breedDescription: 'Good disposition, needs lots of exercise', cost: 1700 }] }, { state: 'RI', dogBreeds: [{ breed: 'Beagle', breedDescription: 'High-energy, tends to howl', cost: 1200 }, { breed: 'Bulldog', breedDescription: 'Low-energy; good apartment dog', cost: 1400 }, { breed: 'Doberman', breedDescription: 'Good disposition, needs lots of exercise', cost: 1700 }] }] };

const transform = (data) => objectScan(['locations[*].dogBreeds[*]'], {
  reverse: false,
  filterFn: ({ gparent, value, context }) => {
    context.push({ state: gparent.state, ...value });
  }
})(data, []);

console.log(transform(dogs));
// => [ { state: 'CT', breed: 'Beagle', breedDescription: 'High-energy, tends to howl', cost: 1200 }, { state: 'CT', breed: 'Bulldog', breedDescription: 'Low-energy; good apartment dog', cost: 1400 }, { state: 'CT', breed: 'Doberman', breedDescription: 'Good disposition, needs lots of exercise', cost: 1700 }, { state: 'RI', breed: 'Beagle', breedDescription: 'High-energy, tends to howl', cost: 1200 }, { state: 'RI', breed: 'Bulldog', breedDescription: 'Low-energy; good apartment dog', cost: 1400 }, { state: 'RI', breed: 'Doberman', breedDescription: 'Good disposition, needs lots of exercise', cost: 1700 } ]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@16.0.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)